# Angular 2- Calling method on child component and displaying result in child component without including child selector in parent component

Tags: angular

In My application i have created one dropdown component which is common component and used in all pages. when i change value in dropdown i want to call method of some other component and want to display the result in its html only not in parent component i.e dropdown component. I am unable to print the result in child component. the constraint here i dont want to use child selector in my parent component to get execute the method. any help will be greatly appreciated.
My code look like this.

dropdown.component.html

```
<ss-multiselect-dropdown [options]="sectionType" class="col-lg-10" [(ngModel)]="optionsModel" (change)="getdropdowndata(optionsModel)">
</ss-multiselect-dropdown>
```

dropdown.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { AssignmentHeadComponent } from './../instructor/assignment-head/assignment-head.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dropdown',
  templateUrl: './dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dropdown.component.css']
})
export class DropdownComponent implements OnInit {
}

constructor(private assignHead:AssignmentHeadComponent) {}

ngOnInit() {  }

  getdropdowndata(event){
    this.sectionId = event;
    this.assignHead.getdata(this.sectionId);
 }
```

assignment-head.component.ts

```
import { DropdownComponent } from './../../dropdown/dropdown.component';
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-assignment-head',
  template:`<div id="data_dv"><div #dataContainer >{{val}}</div></div>`,
  styleUrls: ['./assignment-head.component.css']
})

export class AssignmentHeadComponent implements OnInit {
val:any;
getdata(data){
    this.val = data;
console.log(this.val);
alert(this.val); // alert and console.log able to print the result but not able to display in html.
}

}
```

please share your valid answers. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please make your question more descriptive

Comment: You want to pass data from dropdown component to assignment-head component. Interactions between components can be achieved using `@Input` and `@Output` annotations. `EventEmitter` is used to emit data using events. Please refer to the angular documentation on these topics.

Comment: If components aren't related, use a shared service: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service If they are not related, example works for non-parent-child, but you need to use a behaviorsubject instead of Subject.